Set Interval Js
I want to make a slide show with JS using the setInterval function, but I don't know why my code is not working? While there is no error in console, I have a number of pictures that start with the name "bk" followed by number. I call the pictures using an if statement in function, but the slide effect does not work. It stops at bk1.
Here is my code. If you could help me by explaining how setInterval works.
function slides(sf) {
  sf = sf + 1;
  document.getElementById("centerd")
    .style.backgroundImage = "url(pics/bk" + sf + ".png)";

  if (sf > 2) {
    sf = 1;
  }
}
setInterval(slides(0), 3000);

Also I tried with a for loop:
function slides() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    document.getElementById("centerd")
      .style.backgroundImage = "url(pics/bk" + i + ".png)";

    if (i == 2) {
      i = 1;
    }
  }
}

setInterval(slides, 3000);

But that did not work either.

Try adding some logging to your code to see if your logic is being executed (console.log("Sliding...")). Do you see your logic being executed? If so, add more logging to see if it is correctly looping. We can't give you much direction aside from that since we don't know what your HTML looks like. (Also your first example will never work as you are passing the result of slides(0) as the function, you would need to do setInterval(function(){slides(0)},3000); for that example to work).

"Not working" is completely meaningless. If you're not getting an error, what is it currently doing?

You will need to know your max frames when it comes time to start over back at zero.
Here is a minimal example that breaks this down into bite-sized pieces.


const slideshowEl = document.querySelector('#slideshow'); // Target
const frameCount = 3; // Total frames

let frame = 0; // Current frame index
let intervalId; // Reference to interval

play();

function play() {
  stop();
  intervalId = setInterval(nextFrame, 3000); // Call next every 3 sec
}

// Can be used to cancel
function stop() {
  if (!intervalId) return;
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  intervalId = null;
}

function nextFrame() {
  frame = (frame + 1) % frameCount; // Get next frame
  const imgUrl = `https://placehold.co/300x150?text=Frame+${frame + 1}`;
  slideshowEl.style.backgroundImage = `url('${imgUrl}')`;
}
#slideshow {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-size: cover;
}
<div id="slideshow" style="background-image:url('https://placehold.co/300x150?text=Frame+1"></div>




In your first one
setInterval(slides(0),3000);

This is eqivalent to calling
setInterval(null,3000);

As slides is evaluated and returns nothing
In #2, your loop will run before giving the UI a chance to update. The UI can only update after you have left the function, as the UI is using the same thread. You probably want to keep your counter value either in the function (via this.x or set up a var / field under window to track where in your animation you are.
function slides()
{
  for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    document.getElementById("centerd").style.backgroundImage = "url(pics/bk"+i+".png)";
    if(i==2)
    { 
       i=1;
    }

  }
  
}


At a glance I'm seeing a couple of things wrong here.
First, this doesn't do what you think it does:
setInterval(slides(0),3000);

This calls slides(0) immediately and once, then tries to call the result of that function (which is undefined) every three seconds.
Additionally, this variable only ever has a value of 1:
sf=sf+1;

Because sf is declared and exists only within the scope of that function, and you only ever call the function with the value 0.  So every time the function runs (if you were to call it again successfully), sf would only ever have a value of 1 after the above operation.
So even if it is "working" then it's still only ever setting the background image to the same thing, so nothing ever visibly changes.

Fix both of these things.  First, remove (0) from the function call in setInterval to give setInterval a reference to the function itself, instead of calling the function and using its result:
setInterval(slides,3000);

Then declare sf outside the function so changes to it persist across multiple calls to the function:
// initialize the value
let sf = 0;

function slides() {
  // increment the value
  sf = sf + 1;

  // use the value
  document.getElementById("centerd").style.backgroundImage = "url(pics/bk"+sf+".png)"; 

  // conditionally reset the value
  if(sf > 2) {
    sf = 0;
  }
}

